# BLE Notification when the application is not running

Tags: ios, ios7, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

Is there a possibility to receive BLE notification in your application for a specific UUID or whenever any UUID gets in range while the application is not running? E.g. the same way Push Notifications work?

I tried to google around but so far no helpful information that I could achieve. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible [after the iOS 7.1 update](http://www.macnn.com/articles/14/03/11/may.make.ibeacons.more.practical/)

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [background execution modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html). The app does not need to run in foreground in this case, but it needs to have been started before and has to be in background at least.

iOS7 introduces a Bluetooth state preservation and restoration for long term Bluetooth tasks. By these means, even a terminated app will be restored in background mode by the os.

Comment: But be careful with the restoration. It seems to be very buggy at the moment. So if your app crashes at restore in CoreBluetooth code then it's highly probable that you are doing things right but the framework is failing.